# Jmeter Iteration delay

Tags: jmeter

I have a Thread group which fires of a number of http request. Want I'm trying to do is have a delay at the end of each iteration (not between each request which the constant timer seems to be doing). What is the best way to control the speed of the iterations.

Thanks

Gavin

Answer (score 1):

You can add **Test Action** from *Sampler* where you can provide delays in milliseconds